# Callback() Node Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm very confused about this program. I bought a book called "Node JS, MongoDB, and AngularJS Web Development" by Brad Dayley. I found a program to demonstrate something called closure, and it shows this program as an example. This is only the first part of the program.

```
function logCar(logMsg, callback){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback(logMsg);
    });
}

var cars = ["Ferrari", "Porsche", "Bugatti"];

for(var idx in cars){
    var message = "Saw a " + cars[idx];
    logCar(message, function(){
        console.log("Normal Callback: " + message);
    })
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how this program functions for an entire hour, but I can't figure out what the function of callback(logMsg).

I know this is probably a very basic question, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

callback is any function that you pass to logCar(). When logCar completes doing whatever it is supposed to do, then it will call the callback function. Inside your for loop, you call logCar() like this..

```
logCar(message, function(){
    console.log("Normal Callback: " + message);
})
```

Here, function() {..} is the callback function and it will be called once logCar is done executing. In this case, the callback function you've provided will `console.log` the message you've passed as the first parameter. You could have passed another function that would perform something different as a callback too.

Comment: Why does callback(logMsg) pass the logMsg variable? There's nothing in the parameters of the anonymous function to hold it.

Comment: But you have defined your callback function to take whatever is passed as the first parameter in the `logCar` function. So, any function you pass as a callback will take the logMsg variable automatically.

Comment: At the end of the logCar function, callback(logMsg) happens. That calls the anonymous function. I don't understand how or why the variable logMsg is passed back. If you look at the annonymous function, there is nothing in the parameters to "catch" the logMsg variable.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. So to clarify, the annonymous function I've provided will automatically take the logMsg variable because I passed it as the callback function to logCar?

Comment: Yes. the callback function will automatically take the logMsg variable you've provided as the first parameter to the function that **contains** the callback function(because that's how you've defined your logCar function up above). In this case, you've passed **message** as the first parameter to logCar(), and it will be available to the callback function that it contains.

Comment: You, sir, are so clutch. Rep to you Mr. Bidhan.

Comment: @Jamen You mean Fallout 4. :D

Comment: Aw, I was trying to fit in, 3;

Answer (score 2):

I find these easier to wrap my head around by following the execution path more closely, especially the path that logMsg takes. A good debugger is great for this.

Nothing really happens until that for loop, where a variable named message is defined. At the start it will be "Saw a Ferrari".

There's also an anonymous function right next to "message" that's unfortunately difficult to separate out and define. Because it looks outside of its scope for a variable named "message" that's trapped inside that for loop, we couldn't do on line 6:

```
var someFunction = function(){
      console.log("Normal Callback: " + message);
}
```

...because what's "message"? Nothing outside of that for-loop has access to "message" directly (except as closure, but don't worry about that yet). Note that this function won't execute yet. It's just been created at this point.

So next executes `LogCar("Saw a Ferrari", someFunction...)`. Where's LogCar? Oh, the top. Let's jump there, but for simplicity let's skip process.nextTick. Essentially `someFunction("Saw a Ferrari")` happens here. Where's SomeFunction? Oh, that's that anonymous function that hasn't executed yet. Now its time to execute has arrived. So the process jumps back there to see what's inside it and execute it, which is `console.log("Saw a Ferrari");`

That's done, and the process repeats for "Saw a Porsche" .